# Is Ab/Bb chord in C Major?

Tags: chords, analysis

[image]

above picture has "C major: " in the measure 5.

It seems to say bVII9no5sus4 is one of C major chords, and I can't really see how it is one of C major chords and not one of C minor chords.

Is "C major: " above only refers to measure 6?

Comment: Based on the examples you've posted from the book you're using, combined with the kinds of questions you've posted, I *strongly* recommend finding a different book. If you ask for recommendations in the chat room, I suspect you'll get helpful answers.

Comment: As for this question, it would be helpful to have more context. In particular, what is this example supposed to be illustrating?

Comment: It seems like an Ab chord with a Bb in the bass for some unknown reason.

Comment: It may be an error in the printing, maybe it is c minor?

Comment: So, it's an exercise. What is it actually asking you to do? There must be previous examples to draw upon. If not, a different book may be in the pipeline.

Comment: Expanding Aaron's comment: The issue here is that music theory concepts build on each other, like a lot of math concepts. You're encountering some of these ideas out of order, and are missing some "prerequisite" ideas that support the ones you're seeing. I'm gonna recommend musictheory.net again; go through everything at https://www.musictheory.net/lessons in order and you should have a good baseline. It doesn't explain things as thoroughly as some other sources, but at least it's simple and gradated.

Comment: (One idea, that isn't necessarily the point of these examples, but that is important: You can be "in a key" and still use chords that don't belong to that key. You can "borrow" from other keys, "tonicizing" chords other than I for "mini-modulations," or you can alter diatonic chords, warping notes closer together or farther apart, for fancy purposes (like augmented sixth chords). Learning *how* to do these is an advanced topic, but knowing not to be alarmed at notes "outside the key" should be an early topic.)

Answer (score 1):

The example would be more clear if the key signature was changed to C major in the last two measures. It would be then apparent that to notate Ab/Bb you need to use notes Ab, Eb and Bb which are not diatonic in C major.

Unlike minor keys, which have three commonly used variants (natural, harmonic and melodic), the major key has only one*. Therefore, any chord with non-diatonic tones does not belong to the key. This of course doesn't mean you cannot use it, but it will be then a secondary chord, modal interchange, or entirely unrelated to the key.

**There are two other scales sometimes categorized as "major scale": 1 2 3 4 5 b6 7 and 1 2 3 4 5 b6 b7, but they are used much less commonly than the 3 minor scale variants. Anyway, the chord in question would not belong to any of them.*

Comment: As I look at it could be c minor, maybe a printing error and the key should be c minor?

Comment: My understanding was that each double bar constitutes a new example, and the whole line is not meant to be read left to right as a line of music.

Comment: @AndyBonner Do you think the last example is showing modulation from C minor to C major through the A&flat;/B&flat; chord?

Answer (score 0):

Three of the four notes in the chord are not diatonic to C major so the chord is *not* a diatonic chord in that key. Your book is confusing.

On the other hand, it would not be at all unusual for the chord to turn up in  a piece that's in C major.

Answer (score 0):

Key means tonic. If the tonic chord in your head is a C major chord, then for you, it's in C major, regardless of what pitches are sounding. Tonic is not determined by finding a set of sounding notes and looking it up in a table of physical constants. Tonic is not something you calculate. Tonic is something you feel.

If the author of the book has written that during the Ab/Bb chord the key is C major, it means that he/she considers C major to be the tonic at that point. In other words, the author feels that the Ab/Bb chord would resolve to a C major chord as a home, a chord where the song could naturally end.

A set of sounding pitches does not immediately and instantly define a tonic. The sense of tonic is more complicated, somewhat subjective, and depends on one's sense of rhythm and cultural expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically an vertical combination of tones can be a chord at any time.

You need to know the harmonic style to how to regard any particular tones as chord or non-chord tones.

Your example is using major/minor key labels, so that gives us our harmonic style, and in that style nearly any triad or seventh chord which is diatonic to *some* key can have some functional harmonic analysis. If the cases where there is not a clear function, appropriate labels can be used for those chords.

For chords that don't fit the key signature, but do have harmonic function, the two common functional explanations of those chromatic chords will be:

- secondary dominants, or
- borrowed chords.

In `C` major, and `A` flat major triad could likely be analyzed as a *borrowed* chord, the chord being borrowed from `C` minor, the `Cm:bVI` submediant.

But just like the examples from one of your earlier questions, the example makes a mess of combining jazz chord symbols with Roman numeral analysis. If the harmonic analysis is `bVII9`, there just isn't a good reason to not use a jazz chord symbol of `Bb9sus4`. I suppose `Ab/Bb` is a way to imply a specific voicing, but then again there is staff notation given, so it's already clear what *exactly* to play. Using both an `Ab` chord symbol and Roman numeral `bVII` makes for confusion about what is the chord root and therefore the chord's function.

Anyhow, I think the problem for you...

> It seems to say bVII9no5sus4 is one of C major chords...

From your wording I think your expectation is chord must be diatonic to a key signature, or else they can't function in `C` major.

That way of thinking is too rigid, and does not reflect how tonal harmony actually works. Some of the big things to look for in tonal harmony are:

- what *tone* (not key signature) is the tonic
- what are the chord root progressions
- what is the voice leading
- what is the contour of the bass

An important thing to know for real life harmony is *many* tones take variable form during the course of a piece of music in a given key.

- the *modal scale degrees* can change from major to minor mode and vice versa
- the leading tone and subdominant degrees often "swap" their function during modulations
- secondary dominants can be introduced relative to all major/minor triads diatonic to the key signature

That may be a lot of theory jargon, but the *practical* implication is *every scale degree of a major scale can take a sharp or flat during the course of very common chord progressions*.

When some music is in, for example, `C` major, and you encounter a chord rooted on `Bb`, you don't want to ask whether it's "one of `C` major's chords." You want to ask "how do the chord root progress, and can it be related to a tonic of `C`, or some other tonic?"

In `Ex. 218` the progression is simply `C: bVII9 I`, which doesn't give us much to analyze. As is, I would just call it a *weak progression*, *mode mixture*, and possibly a *deceptive progression* (with the deception being a possible resolution to `Eb` major.) Part of the problem is you gave nothing from the book's text explaining the point of the examples.

One possible way to put the chord in functional context could be...

```
   Bb   Eb   Fm/Ab G7 C 
C: bVII bIII iv6/3 V7 I
```

That gives us roots by descending fifths, bass moving in fifths, an ending with cadential harmony, and mode switch on the tonic chord. All but the last chord are not diatonic to the key signature, but the way the chords progress to the tonic of `C` is pretty clear cut.

Again, I have no idea what the point of the lesson for `ex. 218` is, but the following charts might help you visualize how common chromatic chords relate to a given tonic.

Start with the diatonic triads of `C` major built on each scale degree (scale degrees indicated by `^`):

```
^1 ^2 ^3 ^4 ^5 ^6 ^7 ^1
 C  Dm Em F  G  Am Bo C
```

Next, let's put alterations to the scale degees in the chart, sharp above and flats below:

```
   ^#1   ^#2         ^#4   ^#5               ^#1    

 ^1    ^2    ^3    ^4    ^5    ^6    ^7    ^1
  C     Dm    Em    F     G     Am    Bo    C

         ^b3               b^6   b^7
```

Finally, let's add the common triads and seventh chords associated with those altered scale degrees:

```
     A7    B7          D7    E7                A7
   ^#1   ^#2         ^#4   ^#5               ^#1

 ^1    ^2    ^3    ^4    ^5    ^6    ^7    ^1
  C     Dm    Em    F     G     Am    Bo    C

         ^b3               ^b6   ^b7
           Eb                Ab    Bb
           Cm                Fm
```

That can be reduced to a list of sixteen chords:

```
C Cm Dm D7 Eb Em E7 F Fm G Ab Am A7 Bb Bo B7
```

That is not a complete list. For one thing the various dominant seventh chords could also take the form of diminished triads or diminished seventh chords. But, it is a good working list of common chords, both diatonic to the `C` key signature, and chromatic secondary dominant/borrowed chords, that are commonly encountered in tonal music in `C` major.

Answer (score 0):

Define 'in'?   A♭/B♭ certainly isn't diatonic in C major, it isn't built out of the notes of the C major scale.

But the page doesn't pretend that it is.   It simply states that, from a certain point, the writer intends to analyze the harmony in relation to C major.    That chord isn't 'in' C major in a diatonic sense.  But it might well appear in a piece of music 'in C major'.  If everything was diatonic, why would there be a term 'chromatic chord'?

'♭VII9(no5)(sus4)'  doesn't strike me as a very helpful way of describing a simple ♭VI triad over a ^♭VII 'slash bass'. I suppose it's accurate as far as it goes.  But functional chord labels can run out of usefulness when harmony goes beyond the 'cycle of 5ths' sphere.